# How get coordinates from object?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am beginner in JS. 
I have this object:

```
var lc = L.control.locate().addTo(map);
console.log(lc);
```

it's return: **https://ibb.co/r7T4wP7**

How can I I need 2 variables: long and lat having values from this object (latitude and longtitude). How to get them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Leaflet.Locate plugin](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol), then simply refer to its documentation, which [mentions](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol/blob/gh-pages/README.md#events) that you can use Leaflet built-in location events:

> You can leverage the native Leaflet events `onlocationfound` and `onlocationerror` to handle when geolocation is successful or produces an error. You can find out more about these events in the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile.html#geolocation).

The linked tutorial provides you with a code snippet how to use the location found event to get the coordinates:

```js
function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy; // Note: accuracy is already a radius

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

lc['_event']['latitude'] Will get you to the lattitude and

lc['_event']['longitude'] Will get you to the longitude

For future reference, I would suggest you to Search:
Javascript objects variables

or try:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: it's not working :( I have error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'lc['_event']['latitude']')